# Spring Application won't start: jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist:

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I'm stuck behind this error in IDEA. I was working as usual debugging some classes and everything was working just fine. But at a given moment my spring application stopped initializing and this line appear on the console every time now, and the application remains in a infinite loop, trying to initialize:

```
 The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/user/maven/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/user/maven/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-api.jar,file:/home/user/maven/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/activation.jar,file:/home/user/maven/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3/jsr173_1.0_api.jar,file:/home/user/maven/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb1-impl.jar
```

And these lines :

```
project: 1.1.0-iron-man-SNAPSHOT
Spring Boot version: (v1.5.10.RELEASE)
Java Version: 1.8.0_141
Source Encoding: UTF-8
```

turned out to this:

```
project: @project.version@
Spring Boot version: (v1.5.10.RELEASE)
Java Version: @java.version@
Source Encoding: @project.build.sourceEncoding@
```

I'm didn't change any config files in the project. 
I have tried mvn clean install. 
I have tried to force IDEA to read the maven dependecies again.

None of them have worked.

Comment: Does it help if you remove all IDEA related files/folders (.iml, .idea) and reimport project again as Maven project?

Comment: @Estudeiro  :  Did you find any solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Emmanuel.B sadly, no...

Comment: @Estudeiro sorry, I was on holiday. Could you please, give us the whole error stacktrace ? I got this error once but don't remember how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart helps

Answer (score -1):

First Picture MANIFEST.MF defines the classpath
[image: First Picture MANIFEST.MF defines the classpath]

But they are stored in different maven repository forlders
[image: But they are stored in different maven repository forlders]